# Минимальное/Максимальное значение пары составного ключа

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая таблица:

```
create table KeyPropertyIndex
(
  EntityPropertyId bigint default '0'       not null,
  Value                varchar(1000) default '' not null,
  EntityIds            varbinary(800)           null,
  primary key (EntityPropertyId, Value)
)
```

Каким образом можно вытащить минимальное/максимальное значение пары `(EntityPropertyId, Value)`. Например: `MIN(1, 99887), MAX(1, 100008890)`

При этом `EntityPropertyId` и `Value` (не обязательно число) произвольные значения, уникальна только пара, `(EntityPropertyId, Value)` т.к. это `primary key`

Comment: `SELECT EntityPropertyId, MIN(Value), MAX(Value) FROM KeyPropertyIndex WHERE EntityPropertyId = 1`. Если `Value` - число (хоть и хранится в Varchar) - заменить на `Value+0`.

Comment: А если поле `Value` хранит CSV-пак, то показывайте пример данных.

Comment: @Akina, `EntityPropertyId` не обязательно будет 1

Comment: Ну так дополняйте вопрос-то... снимайте все неоднозначности и непонятности.

Comment: @Akina, дополнил вопрос

Comment: приведите пример тестовых данных лучше  и ожидаемого результата для них. особенно с учетом "необязательно число"